# PSFTP wildcards /*.zip: open for read: permission denied

Tags: putty

I'm using Freesshd and putty's psftp to transfer files.
Now, I can use get ex110111.zip and it works. But if I try to use a wild card get *.zip, I receive an error open for read: permission denied.

How do I use the wildcard to get all the remote zip files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For putting or transferring multiple files use mput and mget.

See http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mgetput .